# How to shorten code for geoJSON file

Tags: json, geojson

I'm building a Florida county map using geoJSON. I downloaded 67 county files and combined them in Cartodb. The current file is huge: 4MB with thousands of lines of code, especially in the coordinates. [Here's what it looks like](http://tny.cz/0c5df7a8). The map works, but it's slow to load on the browser. I've seen other JSON files that are smaller and easier on the browser. Is there a way to shorten the code so they still show the counties on my map? Maybe removing a majority of the coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use TopoJSON which is a topology encoding extension to GeoJSON.
"Rather than representing geometries discretely, geometries in TopoJSON files are stitched together from shared line segments called arcs."
read more:  https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki
repo:
https://github.com/mbostock/topojson

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work :/. I actually found another repo that has Florida county json files (https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json/tree/master/countries/USA/FL). When I put them together, however, my map looks choppy: http://imgur.com/czb2ZhA

Answer (score 0):

Not trivial. One problem is that you have multiple counties, using the same coordinates so they fit together (so the east of county A and the west of county B are identical).

You can analyse your data: If you have a line A->B->C, you can calculate how the area changes if you emit point B. Remove points as long as the total change in area is small. Make sure that if you remove a point in one county it must be removed in the other counties as well. Then you may check how much change you get by leaving out the last decimal of each point. Again, the same point must be changed in the same way in all counties.

Comment: "Remove points as long as the total change in area is small." - many small changes result in one large change.

Comment: This doesn't help because, as you can see in the link, the code is too big to go through and fiddle with each line. Keep in mind the link shows ONE of 67 files used to create a Florida map.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Free API to obtain US County in GeoJson format..u can add multiple counties(since u have a list)

https://www.mashape.com/vanitysoft/boundaries-io

Example query:.../rest/v1/public/boundary?and=true&county=Washington+County&state=MD

[image: county boundary for Washington County in Maryland]

please note that some zipcodes do not fall within a county.

Comment: Do you have a link to the API?

Comment: Welcome. Up Vote/Accept answer when you can! Thanks.